# Issue while connecting to remote weblogic server over proxy

Tags: java, url, proxy, weblogic

I have configured a proxy in my java source code as:

```
systemSettings.put("http.proxyHost", "www.proxyserver.com");
systemSettings.put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
systemSettings.put("http.nonProxyHosts", "10.x.y.z");
```

Here 10.x.y.z is the actual IP of my weblogic server.
But whenever code tried to connect to weblogic server, I receive error as:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3://10.x.y.z:7001: Destination
>   unreachable; nested exception is:     java.net.ProtocolException:
>   unrecognized response from proxy: 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden'; No
>   available router to destination   at
>   weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:216)    at
>   weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)    at
>   weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:153)  at
>   weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate$1.run(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:345)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:340)

It seems that setting http.nonProxyHosts is not working as expected. I tried to find solution over the Internet, but most of them says remove proxy settings. I can not remove proxy, as my code tries to connect to some of the Internet URLs. Also note that, weblogic server is on remote machine.
Can you please give me a hint, what must be the issue here?

Comment: Do you have proxy settings set at system level too?

Comment: I also tried with

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "www.proxyserver.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "10.x.y.z");

But still no luck.

Comment: i ask for that because i had issues with "trailing" multiple proxy settings after various different tries. Its sometimes hard to know which parameter has precedence. Which HTTP library are you using to connect your weblogic?

Comment: Hello Arcadien,
I am using sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler().

Comment: It seems that System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "10.x.y.z") is not working as expected. Not really able to find any reason for this weird behavior.

Comment: Can't you use http://hc.apache.org/ ? it may implement more proxy support. Maybe sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler() does not support it as much as you need

Comment: Hello Arcadien, Do you think that issue is with the library? What must be the issue you feel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I had setup the proxy initially when connection with weblogic was setup. So due to some network restrictions I believe it didnt work. In modified code, I used the same 3 lines to setup proxy:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "false");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "www.proxyserver.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

The only difference is, I did it at exact place where I needed. So for initial connection setup with weblogic proxy wont be used. I also did not have to bypass, weblogic server URL to not to use proxy.

@Arcadien: I appreciate your efforts to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this OTN thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2266321).

From 3rd comment :

> 1. You are setting nonProxyHosts, which doesn't exist as a system property, via System.setProperties().

I haven't read all so far, but it seems the system.properties is not the convenient way to set 
nonProxyHosts.

Did you tried to set it from command line ?

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.foo.com|localhost".
```

Comment: Thanks Arcadien for your answer. But I found on the oracle site that, its a valid proprty to bypass proxy for some severs. For link "http.nonProxyHosts: a list of hosts that should be reached directly, bypassing the proxy. This is a list of patterns separated by '|'. The patterns may start or end with a '*' for wildcards. Any host matching one of these patterns will be reached through a direct connection instead of through a proxy.". Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Hello Arcadien, I had tried -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="10.x.y.z" in VM arguments. It did not work. I have even tried -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=10.x.y.z as mentioned in some of the threads. But this also did not work. I really appreciate your efforts and time to help me. I am also blank at this moment and not able to find the exact problem.

Comment: hehe :) the doc talks about this parameter. but it is once "noProxyHosts" and once "nonProxyHosts" ;) so a test with "noProxyHosts" could be also usefull

Comment: I did not get it. Do you wish me to try with noProxyHosts? I saw your edited comment again. Yes I tried. noProxyHosts also. It also didnt help.

Comment: damn so this typo error in their doc is not either the problem source

Comment: just to known, which JVM are you using?

Comment: its 1.6.24. ans weblogic is 10.3.5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13503/discussion-between-arcadien-and-user613114)